# Not null column in MySQL and integrity check

Tags: mysql, notnull

In MySQL 5.1.48 database I have table with NOT NULL column 'name'. When I update the value of the column to `NULL`, error with yellow exclamation mark (using MySQL Query Browser) is reported and the row is updated (!). The row then contains empty string, it is not displaying the grey NULL indicator.

Is this a bug in the given MySQL version? Or can I magically turn on the constraint checking?

Answer (score 1):

MySQL has multiple [SQL Modes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-sql-mode.html), the behaviour of which can be suprising.  In the mode yours it set in, it sees not null so it provides a default value instead.

Adding "TRADITIONAL" to your SQL mode will cause it to abort the update as you would expect.  You might also be interested in ANSI_QUOTES and STRICT_ALL_TABLES if you want it to behave properly, but lots of code written targetting a MySQL backend will fail if you make things too strict.

Comment: tried this `set sql_mode= STRICT_ALL_TABLES;
update Table set name = null where id = l`, but it silently failed (no error).

Comment: Can you add the output of `SELECT @@sql_mode;` to verify that it has been set correctly?  You shouldn't need to, but you might try setting the server-mode in `my.cnf` and restarting the server instead.

Answer (score 1):

From the reference - *If you are not using strict mode, then whenever you insert an “incorrect” value into a column, such as a NULL into a NOT NULL  column or a too-large numeric value into a numeric column, MySQL sets the column to the “best possible value” instead of producing an error. ...For strings, MySQL stores either the empty string or as much of the string as can be stored in the column*

[Constraints on Invalid Data](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/constraint-invalid-data.html)